# Resize a wallpaper using code?

Tags: android, resize, wallpaper, autoresize, image-resizing

Can you tell me the best way to resize a home screen wallpaper using code based on wether the device is in portrait or landscape mode?

We wish to make sure it will work on many devices.

Please provide code samples.

We are currently using this to set the wallpaper:

```
myWallpaperManager.setResource(R.drawable.thewallpaper);
```

The wallpaper is also a png file.

Update:

Based on the code from coder_for_life22, I changed it to this:

```
        try {
            myWallpaperManager.setResource(R.drawable.kabaday1);

            myCurrentImageName = "kabaday1";

            Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),
                    R.drawable.kabaday1);

            Bitmap bitmapResized = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(myBitmap, 600, 300,
                    false);

            myWallpaperManager.setBitmap(bitmapResized);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

It scales the image but Android is re-displaying and expanding the image with the same image size as it did before the scale down, only this time the image quality is on the fuzzy side and still seems zoomed in and not showing the entire image that should be scaled down.

Strange behaviour. Maybe there is some more coding I need to add to this so it really scales down and remains sharp. At least I think it should do that because the image should be smaller.

There are many apps out there doing the same thing. I only wish I knew how they are doing it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to resize the image using this

```
 Bitmap bitmapResized = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(src, dstWidth, dstHeight, filter);

 myWallpaperManager.setBitmapResource(bitmapResized);
```

EDIT: You may also need to change the scaleType of the imageview you are using. by inserting this in your xml where imageview is located.

```
  android:scaleType = "FIT_CENTER"
```

OR you can do it programmatically by inserting this in your above code.

```
myWallpaperManager.setScaleType(ImageView.FIT_CENTER);
```

That should get rid of the zoomed in look you are getting.

Comment: Hi coder_For_Life22, I changed it based on your example code and it does scale down but I see Android re-sizing it at the same time and it remains in a zoomed in state instead of showing the entire image on the screen. Please see the changes in the "Update" section of my post.

Comment: Hi coder_ForLife22, This app does not use an ImageView for the wallpaper because it is a slide-show type app that changes the wallpaper every minute. Also when I typed the full stop after myWallpaperManager the intellisense did not show setScaleType as a choice because I wanted to see if it would take a line such as myWallpaperManager.setScaleType(bitmapResized). Is there another way to do it?